# Change array values to number from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, numbers

I have an array with these values:

```
var items = [Thursday,100,100,100,100,100,100]
```

I'm grabbing these from the URL query string so they are all string values. I want all columns except the first to be number. The array may vary in the number of columns, so is there a way to set this so items[0] is always a string, but items[n] is always a number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"...is there a way to set this so items[0] is always a string, but items[n] is always a number?"*

Use `.shift()` to get the first, `.map()` to build a new Array of Numbers, then `.unshift()` to add the first back in.

```
var first = items.shift();
items = items.map(Number);
items.unshift(first);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/EcuJu/

---

We can squeeze it down a bit like this:

```
var first = items.shift();
(items = items.map(Number)).unshift(first);
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/EcuJu/1/

---

- [MDN `Array.prototype.map` shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility)

Comment: +1 for .map(Number). It might be useful to add browser support info (for example no support for IE7 / IE8)

Comment: @jenson-button-event: Has better support than `items.Skip(1).Cast<int>()` :P

Comment: @jen: Heh, *"pig-headed"*... OINK!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work for you. You could set whatever default number you liked instead of 0.

```
var items = ["Thursday","100","100","100","100","100","100"], i;
for (i = 1; i < items.length; i++)
{
    if(typeof items[i] !== "number")
    {
        items[i] = isNaN(parseInt(items[i], 10)) ? 0 : parseInt(items[i], 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: In fact, if you know they're all strings then you might as well omit the `typeof` check.

Answer (score 1):

parseFloat() will convert your string to a number.

Here is a sample code for modern browsers (won't work in IE7/IE8):

```
var convertedItems=items.map(function(element,index){
  // Convert array elements with index > 0
  return (index>0)?parseFloat(element):element;
});
```

There's also a parseInt() method for conversion to integers:

```
parseInt(element,10)
```